# Capistrano 3: How can I suppress status output?

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3, sshkit

I've created a Capistrano task to execute a rake command. I plan to redirect the output (STDOUT) to a file. E.g.

`cap production invoke:rake TASK=mytask > out`

This works, but my output includes some additional Capistrano status output, e.g.

`00:00 invoke:rake
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake mytask
...
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@mydomain.com 11.399s`

Is there any way to suppress this?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably stderr output. If so, you can redirect standard error to standard out like so:

```
cap production invoke:rake TASK=mytask > out 2>&1
```

Comment: will_in_wi, that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think I figured out a pretty good solution.

The key was to use capture (not documented in Capistrano 3.x, but still works). 
https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano-2.x-docs/blob/master/2.x-DSL-Action-Inspection-Capture.md

```
namespace :invoke do
  desc "Execute a rake task on a remote server"
  task :rake do
    if ENV['TASK']
      on roles(:app) do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          puts capture :rake, ENV['TASK']
        end
      end
    else
      puts "\n\nFailed! You need to specify the 'TASK' parameter!",
          "Usage: cap <stage> invoke:rake TASK=your:task"
    end
  end
end
```